# Classes and 2D Dynamic Array

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm having troubles getting a 2D class array to get filled with other class objects.

**Base class:**

```
class Base {
protected:
    int x, y;
    int moves;
    char name;
    bool occupied;
public:
    Base();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Base& test);
};
```

**Derived class:**

```
class Derived : public Base {
private:
    const int x = 10;
    const int y = 60;
    Base **array;
public:
    Derived();
    void printBoard();
};
```

**Constructor of Derived class:**

Creates the 2d dynamic array

```
Derived::Derived() {
    array = new Base*[x];
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
         array[i] = new Base[y];
}
```

**Derived class 2:**

```
class Derived2: public Base{
public:
    Derived2(int x, int y);
};
```

*How do I get the 2D array to accept and afterwards correctly display the objects in that array?*

Whenever I try

```
Derived[x][y] = new Derived2(x,y);
```

It just doesn't seem to work and I really think I'm stuck on this for a while :(

Comment: What's `Derived` in the last code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the relationship between `Derived` and `Base`:

1. `Derived` **is a** `Base`
2. `Derived` **has an** array of `Base`s

You cannot do `Derived[x][y]`, this requires `Derived` to have a user-defined `operator[]` that would return another array (if it was possible to make it `static`). If you want to access `array`, you need an instance of `Derived` and provide an "getter" function for `array`.

You need to have a 2D array of pointers to do polymorphism: `Base ***array;`, allocate it like:

```
array = new Base**[x];
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) 
     array[i] = new Base*[y];
// this gives you 2D array of uninitialized pointers
```

And you're forgetting to delete this array in `Base`'s destructor. [This is how you do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053336/deallocating-memory-in-a-2d-array/33053364#33053364). Resource management should be the first thing you implement and make sure it's right. Logic follows after that.

This is the "getter" function (`public`):

```
Base ***Derived::getArray() const
{
    return array; // array is private, you access it with this function
}
```

And you use it in the code:

```
int x = 1, y = 2;
Derived d; // create an instance - this calls Derived's constructor, allocates array

d.getArray()[x][y] = new Derived2(x, y);
```

I recommend using `std::vector` (or `std::array`, since you have constant dimensions) instead of dynamically allocated arrays.

Comment: This is a Turtle vs Hare race.
The array of `Base` will contain a few Hares and Turtles.

Comment: Thank you, will test this out.
Our assignment requires using dynamically allocated arrays, yes, with `std::vector` it would be much easier

Comment: Tested, made progress, but weird errors appeared, as
`'delete' cannot convert from 'Base' to 'void'`
and `delete d.getArray()[x][y];` gets `must be a pointer to complete object type`
Also there's a problem with operator=

Comment: Wow, this fixed nearly everything, thank you!
Just a "getter" function, that returns the `char name`, broke
Something about `expression must have a class type` and `left of getName() must have class/struct/union` 
when trying to retrieve the `name` from the 2D array of pointers.

Comment: Show me how you're doing it. Also `char` is a single character name, is that what you want?

Comment: `char` is just a symbol like `T` for turtle `B` for bush and `H` for hare.
the code for "getter" function is `return name;`

What I was trying to do was `if(array[x][y].getName() == '?')`in `void printBoard()` function

edit: `char getName()` function is located in the `Base` class

Comment: `array[x][y]` returns a pointer, you have to do `array[x][y]->getName()`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but hmm, is there any way I could contact you in private? I could message some contact details to you on your youtube account, would really appreciate the help, sorry, so noob at this :/

Comment: Why would you need that? If you're having a problem just post here again. Maybe I'll be around, maybe some other, better people.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep asking questions on here, thank you a million for the help! :)

Comment: Ask a new question about that, I don't really know what it is. Don't forget to post the complete code.